# creating opposite direction lanes in SUMO network

Tags: sumo

I am trying to simulate an overtaking in my network, i came across a suggestion to use  to create opposite lanes. It is however not working. I don't know if i omitted something. I also tried the command

```
netconvert --opposite.guess true --node-files (name) --edge-files (name) -t (name) -o (outputfile)
```

I have attached my code from the edge file.

```xml
<edges>
    <edge id="0" from="0" to="2" type="1">
        <neigh lane="a0"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="2" from="2" to="4" type="1">
        <neigh lane="a2"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="4" from="4" to="6" type="1">
        <neigh lane="a4"/>
    </edge>
</edges>
```

This is the result in the terminal after netconvert:

```
netconvert --node-files curve.nod.xml --edge-files curve.edg.xml -t curves.type.xml -o curve.net.xml
Warning: Removing unknown opposite lane 'a0' for edge '0'.
Warning: Removing unknown opposite lane 'a10' for edge '10'.
Warning: Removing unknown opposite lane 'a11' for edge '11'.
Warning: Removing unknown opposite lane 'a13' for edge '13'.
Warning: Removing unknown opposite lane 'a15' for edge '15'.
Warning: Removing unknown opposite lane 'a2' for edge '2'.
Warning: Removing unknown opposite lane 'a4' for edge '4'.
Warning: Removing unknown opposite lane 'a6' for edge '6'.
Warning: Removing unknown opposite lane 'a7' for edge '7'.
Warning: Removing unknown opposite lane 'a8' for edge '8'.
Warning: Removing unknown opposite lane 'a9' for edge '9'.
Success.
```

Answer (score 0):

The lanes you specify in `neigh` need to exist. A valid example would be:

```
<edges>
    <edge id="a0" from="2" to="0" type="1"/>
    <edge id="0" from="0" to="2" type="1">
        <neigh lane="a0_0"/>
    </edge>
</edges>
```

This is only correct when the edge a0 has only a single lane. The number after the `_`denotes the lane index and should be the last lane on the given edge.

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean by lane index. Aren't the lanes created from the edges?.

Comment: The lanes of an edge are numbered from outmost to innermost, so a0_0 is the rightmost lane (in right hand networks) a0_1 the second and so on. The number after the underscore is usually called the lane index.